# ¿Como Puedo Aplicar una Condicion "if o while" a un Arreglo de estructura "struct" en C?

Tags: c, array, estructuras

Tengo este problema y en el código que nos dan de ejemplo se manejan estructuras pero por lo que tengo entendido una estructura no se puede comparar, lo que yo quiero hacer es comparar si el registro 1 es mayor a 18 entonces que incremente un contador y así para lo demás.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿ Podrías mostrarnos el código que tienes y cual es el problema ? Y eso de `un arreglo de estructura` no queda muy claro lo que es. ¿ Quieres comparar estructuras completas ? ¿ Ciertos campos individuales ? Quizá deberías pasarte por [como elaboro una buena pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Un saludo.

Comment: Ya Edité lo que tengo que hacer, espero que ahora sea un poco más entendible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes comparar los valores de los elementos de las estructuras accediendo con la notación `estructura.elemento` o en el caso de que la estructura sea referenciada con un puntero con `estructura->elemento`.

Como ejemplo si la estructura y el arreglo o vector son de la siguiente manera:

```
struct persona{
    int sexo;
    int edad;
    int estado;
};

struct persona lista[15];
```

Puedes escanear la lista de la siguiente manera:

```
// variables para almacenar los resultados
int hombressolteros = 0;
int hombrescasados = 0;
int mujeressolteras = 0;
int mujerescasadas = 0;
int totalsolteros = 0;
int totalcasados = 0;
int menoresedad = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < 15; i++) {

    // Comprobar si es mayor de edad
    if (lista[i].edad < 18) {
        menoresedad++;
    }
    // Comprobar si es hombre
    else if (lista[i].sexo == 1) {

        // Determinar si esta casado
        if (lista[i].estado == 1) {
            hombrescasados++;
        }
        else {
            hombressolteros++;
        }
    }
    // si es mujer
    else {
        // Determinar si es casada
        if (lista[i].estado == 1) {
            mujerescasadas++;
        }
        else {
            mujeressolteras++;
        }
    }
}

// Totales
totalcasados = hombrescasados + mujerescasadas;
totalsolteros = hombressolteros + mujeressolteras;
```

Comment: Si le haces la tarea sin que el antes se lo curre lo más mínimo no va a aprender absolutamente nada y tu no vas a obtener demasiada reputación que digamos

Comment: @eferion A parte de intentar ayudar un poco, mas que nada me sirve a mi mismo para practicar y mejorar en el lenguge.

Comment: Pero para practicar tu no es necesario que publiques la respuesta... otra cosa sería que al intentar resolverlo te encontrases con dudas e hicieses la correspondiente pregunta